# HTML 5 Geolocation API and Google Geocoding Terms and Usage Limits

Tags: google-geocoding-api

If I use HTML 5 Geolocation API on my website and if the web browser of the website visitor uses Google Geolocation Services (e.g. Google Chrome) to detect his/her location, will I be still bound to Terms and Usage Limits of Google Geocoding API even if I am not using it directly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google Geolocation Services through Chrome are not the Google Maps API Geocoding services. It's a different service, and as far as I know binds the user not the website creator.

Answer (score 0):

It is different from google geolocation api. It shall be from w3.org and therefore no limitation.